# GetWindowText with char[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I am quite new to Windows programming. I am trying to retrieve the name of a window.

```
char NewName[128];
GetWindowText(hwnd, NewName, 128);
```

I need to use a char[] but it gives me the error of wrong type.
From what I read, LPWSTR is a kind of char*.

How can I use a `char[]` with `GetWindowText` ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: LPWSTR means Long Pointer to Wide String, ie a string made of wide characters, the `wchar_t` type, not `char`.

Comment: You say you `need to use a char[]`, what is your reason?

Comment: NewName is used with strcmp.

Comment: @MaT There is a variant of strcmp that works with wide chars. But more importantly, there are operators `==` and `<` for `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably compiling a Unicode project, so you can either:

- Explicitly call the ANSI version of the function (`GetWindowTextA`), or
- Use `wchar_t` instead of `char` (`LPWSTR` is a pointer to `wchar_t`)

Answer (score 1):

For modern Windows programming (that means, after the year 2000 when Microsoft introduced the Layer for Unicode for Windows 9x), you're far better off using **"Unicode"**, which in C++ in Windows means using **`wchar_t`**.

That is, use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, and use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Remember to define `UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>`. It's also a good idea to define `NOMINMAX` and `STRICT`. Although nowadays the latter is defined by default.

Answer (score 1):

When calling Windows APIs without specifying an explicit version by appending either A (ANSI) or W (wide char) you should always use `TCHAR`. `TCHAR` will map to the correct type depending on whether `UNICODE` is `#define`d or not.